# multiple forms in same page

Tags: asp.net, forms, multiple-forms

i have been looking for the solution for a long time but could not find the 
 solution. Please help me to find the solution.

i have a form in x.aspx page. the form is below

```
<form name="add_fund_conf" runat="server" action="y.aspx" method="POST">
    <div >
        <b>Add Funds From:</b>
    </div>
    <div >                                            
        <select id="add_funds_from" runat="server" name="add_funds_from" >
            <option value="">Select Gateway</option>
            <option value="1">Perfect Money </option>
            <option value="2">BitCoin </option>
            <option value="3">Payeer </option>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <b>Amount To Add:</b> USD
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="amount_to_add"  runat="server" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Funds" />
    </div>
</form>

and these are the javascript functions  in the head of  the y.aspx page 
<script language="JavaScript">
    function PM() {
        document._xclick.submit();
    }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function Payza() {
        document.formPayza.submit();
    }
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function Payeer() {
        document.formPayeer.submit();
    }
</script>
```

And the following form in the body section

```
<form name="_xclick" id="_xclick" runat="server" action="https://perfectmoney.is/api/step1.asp" method="POST">
</form>

<form name="formPayza" id="formPayza" runat="server" action="https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php" method="post">                         
</form>

<form name="formPayeer" method="GET" action="https://payeer.com/merchant/">
</form>
```

in the code behind file i have written the following code.i have been looking for the solution for a long time but could not find the 
solution. Please help me to find the solution.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    int add_funds_from = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["add_funds_from"]);
    int amount_to_add = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["amount_to_add"]);
    if(add_funds_from==1)
    {                
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "PM();", true);
    }
    else if (add_funds_from==2)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "Payza();", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "Payeer();", true);
    }
}
```

But the page showing following error

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code. 
>            Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

I am newbie in coding. So please ignore if i make any mistakes. i have been looking for the solution for a long time but could not find the 
 solution. Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in Advance for helping.

Comment: Webforms doesn't work that way. You cannot have multiple forms on a single page.  webforms wraps the entire page in an all encompassing form.  You need to read a tutorial on webforms and how to user server side controls.

Answer (score 0):

One option is create separate aspx pages for each of your forms then use iframes in your main form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <h1>Main Form</h1>

    <iframe src="payza.aspx"></iframe>
    <iframe src="payeer.aspx"></iframe>
    etc.

</asp:Content>
```

The other thing is, each `RegisterClientScriptBlock` must have a unique name. You have "blah" for all of them, but they must all be different.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "PM();", true);
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blahza", "Payza();", true);
etc.
```

That is, if the scripts are going to the same page. If you end up with different pages in iframes then it won't matter. (I think. Maybe use different names anyway so they are unique.)